# PHP get data from another page

Tags: php

I have a log in page.First, when the user enters the correct username and password he will move to managing page. But, I want to fetch his database information for another page. I mean I detect the username and password, then get other rows from that.

I know which I can use sessions, but session gives me one value and this is want I do not need.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['username'])){
        if(isset($_POST['password'])){
            $user_id = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users`");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                $db_id = $row[0];
                $db_user_id = $row["user_id"];
                $db_user_pass = $row["user_pass"];
                $db_user_type = $row["user_type"];
                $db_user_name = $row["user_name"];
                if($db_user_id == $user_id && $db_user_pass == $password && $db_user_type == "manager"){
                    header("Location: manager.php");
                    $_SESSION['currentmanager'] = $user_id;
                }elseif($db_user_id == $user_id && $db_user_pass == $password && $db_user_type == "user"){
                     $_SESSION['currentuser'] = $user_id;
                    header("Location: users.php");
                }elseif($db_user_id == $user_id && $db_user_pass == $password && $db_user_type == "teacher"){
                    $_SESSION['currentteacher'] = $user_id;
                    header("Location: teachers.php");
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: *"but session gives me one value"* - What do you mean by "one" value? Plus, I highly suggest you add `exit;` after all your headers.

Comment: `$_SESSION['some_array'] = array(1,3,4);`

Comment: I mean you can put a variable in that. But you can't get other information using that session. My problem is to detect username and password entered in log in page for managing page to fetch information.

Comment: You can assign sessions to pretty much anything you want, even an array, as "u_mulder" stated, a fetched row for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$_SESSION['some_array'] = array(1,3,4);
```

as @u_mulder said.

Thanks.

Comment: Enjoy the ride :) *Cheers*

Comment: Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements). This is a must nowadays.